# Julia Mathlink installation, could not find dynamic library

Tags: julia, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to install MathLink.jl but I can't find the dynamic library libML64.dll. Or how to install WSTP (or if it's needed to be installed... information on it seems very scarce). I'm currently using the paid version of Mathematica 12.1.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have tried setting both environmental variables before building the package, but it didn't work in any of the folders I tried. In this issue https://github.com/JuliaInterop/MathLink.jl/issues/18 the developer sets to "SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions" on linux, but it didn't work on Windows. The closest candidate I could think of was wstp64i4.dll, which is located in SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64.

I also tried with the Wolfram Engine, thinking that maybe my Mathematica installation was corrupted, but both fail to build/evaluate.

I could install on linux with the Wolfram Engine, without setting anything.

Comment: From the package readme, you can tell the library location, BEFORE building the package, by just setting the environmental variable `JULIA_MATHLINK` (and then type `] build MathLink`)

Comment: @Antonello, perhaps I wasn't clear in my question. I've set it before building, the question is set it to where? There is no libML64.dll. I also tried adding the same folder the developer indicated in this issue https://github.com/JuliaInterop/MathLink.jl/issues/18 , but it didn't work. The closest candidate I found was named wstp64i4.dll, and is located in SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64.